# No Wireless connection from slave ADSL router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have 3 DSL router:Netis,Tenda & TP-link and 1 ASDL router:Tenda. I am using Netis as a main router and DHCP is enabled here. All other routers are connected to main router LAN-LAN connection and have disabled DHCP on all other routers. 
All DSL routers are working fine. The ADSL secondary router connection are working fine through LAN port but when  trying to connect throught WIFI it is not connecting. Some of devices are able to connect throught wifi and some are not. Is there any solution or workaround? 
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you are using 4 DSL routers? Are you trying to run some sort of load balancing?